# animate multiple element over slider img with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

Please I Have A Slider Imgs and Some Multiple text Over The Slider , I Want To Let The text Animate with the first img and then when the first img Slide , the text hide and show another text over the second image , I Tried But Nothing productive , I'm Bit  Beginner in jquery .

```
$("header img").each(function () {

    if ($(".img1:visible")) {

        $("header .hd-text h1").css("visibility", "visible");

    } else if ($(".img2:visible")) {

        $("header .hd-text h1").css("visibility", "hidden");

        }
})
```

thats My HTML Code For Slider And Texts .

```
<div class="slider-header">
    <div class="slider-content">
       <img class="img1" src="Imgs/header-pic1.jpeg" alt="Header Picture">
       <img class="img2" src="Imgs/header-pic2.jpeg" alt="Header Picture">
    </div>
```

```
<div class="hd-text">
            <div class="container">
                <h1><span>ProWeb</span> Stands Next To You<br> Until You Get Satisfied .</h1>
                <p>We Are Skilled In Web Design at All , What Make Us Special Is Support<br> Just One quick Message And All is Fixed .</p>
                <a class="btn-hd actv-btn" href="#">About Us</a>
                <a class="btn-hd" href="#">Get Satisfied</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: not like that .. it's depending on how your slider works .. but your posted code will not work anyway .. try to find the interval which responsible on creating the loop in the slider  .. after that you can create a `setInterval()` function to slide text as same as images

Comment: man thanks you very very much for your comment , but man my slideshow slide Every 5 sec , So Should i put play between the Two texts , i mean everyone fadein in 5sec and then fadeout and the pther fadein

Comment: Is it just one `$("header .hd-text h1")` you have?? or some `h1`'s which equals images number??

Comment: normally i have a slider which contains 2 Images , Every image slide in 5sec , and i Have 2 box of texts , then I want every text shown with a specific image with loop

Comment: it'll be better to provide your html code . code that explain how your slider and your text related and what's unique for 1st text to show with 1st image and 2nd text to show with 2nd image .. your code should explain that

Comment: i put my code slider and text , there is 2 sort of texts ,

Comment: This code will show you how to do that https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/t6qbw47n/ .. it'll give you a main idea ... Good Luck :)

Comment: Thanks Man , I Tried but it doesn't work with the interval of imgs , anyway thanks you very much